# Factoring $a^{k} - b^{k}$

Tags: factoring, binomial-theorem

I am a bit lost how to factor $a^{k} - b^{k}$. I know it links to the binomial theorem but I can't remember how to do it. Could anyone explain?

Comment: From question 712758:

$Q=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{a^{n-i}b^i}=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$
 
$a^n-b^n=(a-b)Q=(a)Q+Q(-b)$
  
$\begin{matrix}
(a)Q&=&a^n&+a^{n-1}b&+a^{n-2}b^2&+\dots&+a^2b^{n-2}&+ab^{n-1}&\\
+Q(-b)&=&&-a^{n-1}b&-a^{n-2}b^2&-\dots&-a^2b^{n-2}&-ab^{n-1}&-b^n\\
\end{matrix}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to see with the binomial theorem, but with the geometric series. Actually it's a high-school formula:
$$1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{k-1}=\frac{1-x^k}{1-x},$$
 which also reads as
$$1-x^k=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{k-1})$$
whence, settink $x=\dfrac ba$, and multiplying both sides by $a^k$, one obtains:
$$a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+a^{k-3}b^2+\dots+b^{k-1}).$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\begin{align}a^k-b^k&=(a-b)\left(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\cdots+ab^{k-2}+b^{k-1}\right)\end{align}$$